# Error in loading the iFrame in Salesforce 1 Platform:

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, jquery, mobilesdk

Scenario : 
I have built desktop based Force.com platform and now i have enabled the Salesforce 1 Mobile app on my environment. Now if i try to load the same Desktop based Quote Detail page on Iphone 5 emulator on Google Chrome, i get this error

**: [Report Only] Refused to frame 'https://c.na10.visual.force.com/apex/QuoteDetail?id=a0RF000000IYFfjMAH&sfdcIFrameOrigin=https%3A%2F%2Fna10.salesforce.com&isdtp=p1&sfdcIFrameHost=web' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.**

Please if some one could help me figure out the reason. Really appreciate it

From the comments, here is the quote detail page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Quote__c" title="Quote Detail" sidebar="false">
    <apex:form >
        <c:QuoteDetail theQuoteId="{!Quote__c.Id}" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Yes sure, but it is going to be long. I have a QuoteDetail.page, QuoteDetail.component which is embedded in the QuoteDetail.page and QuoteDetail.controller. As well as QuoteDetail.css file. I will attach the QuoteDetail.page and QuoteDetail.component

Comment: I am unable to add the code as it says out of space for characters

Comment: Can you create a smallest possible VF page that still reproduces the error then :) We certainly don't want to read pages and pages of your logic...

Comment: QuoteDetail.page                                          <apex:page standardController="Quote__c" title="Quote Detail" sidebar="false">
 <apex:form >
  <c:QuoteDetail theQuoteId="{!Quote__c.Id}" />
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>

Comment: The QuoteDetail i.e <c:QuoteDetail> is a custom made component within the application. Any thoughts as to what might be causing the error

Comment: Can you also attach a super shortened version of the QuoteDetail custom component? There is a very good chance that this component is the cause of your problems.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing this error due to a Content Security Policy (CSP) breach - a CSP is an HTTP header that defines a bunch of policies for resources.  You are falling foul of the frame-src restriction. You can read more about this at:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/

If the iphone5 emulator you are using is a chrome app, the default behaviour for those is to disallow external resources in iframes:

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy (search for frame-src).

If you don't have a real device I would use the desktop version of Salesforce1 (/one/one.app) with the browser resized appropriately.

Comment: I am also running into the same "Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'" error. I am attempting show google maps in a lightning component, I tried switching to "<webview" instead of Iframe but with no luck. Can anyone advise an easy way to whitelist an address for use in lightning components or other solution?